# How to combine Regex with removing space and # character

Tags: php, regex

I have this array, that I need to remove white spaces and # hashtag character:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'darwin' (length=6)
  1 => string ' #nature' (length=8)
  2 => string ' explore' (length=8)
  3 => string ' galapagos' (length=10)
  4 => string 'karma' (length=5)

  foreach ($feedSinglePosts["hashtags_list"] as $key=>&$item) {
     $item = preg_replace('/(\s|^)/', '', $item);
     $item = preg_replace('/\#+/', '', $item);
  }
```

The Regex above works well but **I want to make it one line if possible**. 
When I do: `/(\s|^)\#+/` it outputs this:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'darwin' (length=6)
  1 => string 'nature' (length=6)
  2 => string ' explore' (length=8)
  3 => string ' galapagos' (length=10)
  4 => string 'karma' (length=5)
```

How to make the regex on liner that removes white spaces and3 hashtag.

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~^[\s#]+~', '', $feedSinglePosts["hashtags_list"])`

Comment: BTW, you don't need `foreach`. You can give an array to `preg_replace()`, it will return an array with all the replacements.

Comment: BTW you don't need `preg_replace` just use `str_replace`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `|^` in the first regexp? The beginning of the string isn't a character, there's nothing to replace.

Comment: Doesn't [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60509889/3832970) help you?

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew, the '~^[\s#]+~' regex somehow didn't work on my code. Tried it in few variations. I saw it works in the demo you posted, so I guess the problem is in my code.

Comment: `$feedSinglePosts["hashtags_list"] = preg_replace('~^[\s#]+~', '', $feedSinglePosts["hashtags_list"]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the characters will be at the beginning or end.  If so then no need for loops or regex:

```
array_walk($feedSinglePosts["hashtags_list"], function(&$v) { $v = trim($v, "\n\r #"); });
```

If you need to remove them anywhere:

```
$feedSinglePosts["hashtags_list"] = str_replace(["\n","\r"," ","#"], "", $feedSinglePosts["hashtags_list"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex way with `array_walk()` and `trim()`,

```
<?php
    $array = ['darwin' ,' #nature',' explore', ' galapagos','karma'];
    function remove_hash_space(&$value,$key){
         $value = trim($value,'# ');
     }
    array_walk($array, 'remove_hash_space');  
    print_r($array);
   ?>
```

*DEMO:* https://3v4l.org/nOadH

**OR** with single line `array_map()`,

```
 $array = array_map(function($e){return trim($e,'# ');},$array);
```

*DEMO:* https://3v4l.org/OaS1F

Comment: Is php only method better than using regex? In terms of reliability and quickens? really not familiar with Regex, so curious to understand whats better in general?

Comment: regex is cool but when other built-in do it best then try to use it instead of Regex

Comment: @idm keeping regex in your arsenal is good practice. I personally like regex very much,but as I said earlier using the built-in function of language is best to me

Comment: Thank you Ill definitely look into it more!

Comment: @idm best of luck mate, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$arr = ['darwin',' #nature',' explore',' galapagos','karma'];
print_r( preg_replace('~^[\s#]+~', '', $arr) );
// => Array ( [0] => darwin [1] => nature [2] => explore [3] => galapagos [4] => karma )
```

See the [regex demo](https://3v4l.org/9HNMK)

The `^[\s#]+` pattern matches 1 or more occurrences (`+`) of whitespace or `#` characters (`[\s#]`) at the start of the string (`^`).

If your strings may contain some wierd Unicode whitespace, consider adding the `u` modifier: `~^[\s#]+~u`.

If you only need to handle horizontal whitespace, replace `\s` with `\h`.

Comment: You should use `var_dump()` so you can see whether the spaces were replaced.